# Как получить данные из mongodb используя mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

user модель mongoose

```
let users;

user.find((err, data) => {
   users = data;
   console.log(data); // выводит данные
});

console.log(users); //undefined
```

console.log(data) - выводит данные

console.log(users) - undefined

Как получить значения data?

Comment: Тут получение данных происходи ассинхронно. `users = data;` вызывается после `console.log(users);`. Ознакомьтесь в работой ассинхронного кода в JS (промисы, async ... await ...)

Comment: у вас ассинхронный вызов (происходит после нахождения данных в бд). поэтому console.log(users) происходит раньше чем, users=data